# all command in jdk/bin can not execute

Tags: jdk

for example i type `jmap` in terminal, it will show:

```
The program 'jmap' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
root@CNS-ETNEXUS1:/usr/lib/jvm# The program 'jmap' can be found in the following packages:
No command 'The' found, did you mean:
 Command 'the' from package 'the' (universe)
The: command not found
```

type `jstack` is the similar result,.

i follow this [askubuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) to install java7, but when i receive this machine, some one already install some openjdk, i guess that's why has the openjdk option.

how to fix it? i do not want to use absolute path every time.

`echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/share/centrifydc/sbin:/usr/share/centrifydc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: i donot want to use it, i want to know how to come with this and how to use my new jdk7's bin folder

Comment: then remove completely you open-jdk . Go to the sofware-center and type Java.  If installed remove open-jdk-7 and 6 runtime

Comment: i only has shell, no x11

Comment: Then simply  type:      sudo apt-get purge openjdk-7-jre    and then sudo apt-get purge openjdk-7-jdk